# What does it look like for $R/N$ to contain a proper nontrivial ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently trying to understand the proof for the statement "$M$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ iff $R/M$ is a field." In the proof the author assumes that $R/M$ is not a field because $a+M$ doesn't have an inverse for some $a \not \in M$. Part of the proof involves the claim that $(R/M)(a+M)$ is an ideal of $R/M$ and since it doesn't have $1 + M$, it claims that we can see that $\gamma^{-1} [(R/M)(a+M)]$ is a proper ideal of $R$ properly containing $M$ (where $\gamma$ is the canonical homomorphism from $R$ to $R/M$.)

While reading this proof I started becoming somewhat confused about what a proper nontrivial ideal looks like in $R/N$. I wrote out a few elements, like $a_1 + N, a_2 +N, ... a_i + N$ and imagined that a nontrivial ideal of this would be some set of elements from here that satisfy the properties of an ideal. However, my understanding is that the inverse of such a proper nontrivial ideal would be some ideal $M$ that contains $N$. I'm confused about how that is possible because then the proper nontrivial ideal of $R/N$ would be of the form $b_1 + M, b_2 + M... b_j + M$. In particular, I am having difficulty understanding the relationship with the two sets (how is the second set contained in the first?) Could someone please clarify this?

Comment: The entire ring, or ${0},$ could be trivial ideals of a ring

Comment: By the Isomorphism Theorems, the ideals of $R/M$ are precisely the ideals of the form $I/M = \{a+M\mid a\in I\}$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ that contains $M$.